# R Error in CRS(x): PROJ4 argument-value pairs must begin with +

Tags: r, r-raster

read a color space image into a variable

```
img <- stack('BlueMarbleJuly.tif')
```

project the raster into a nes coordinate system. Project Robinson

```
img.merc <- projectRaster(img, crs = st_crs(3857)[[2]])
```

and I get an error

> Error in CRS(x) : 
>         PROJ4 argument-value pairs must begin with +: PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
>           BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
>               DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
>                   ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
>                       LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
>               PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
>                   ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
>               ID["EPSG",4326]],
>           CONVERSION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo-Mercator",
>               METHOD["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator",
>                   ID["EPSG",1024]],
>               PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
>                   ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
>                   ID["EPSG",8801]],
>               PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
>                   ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
>                   ID["EPSG",8802]],
>               PARAMETER["False easting",0,
>                   LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
>                   ID["EPSG",8806]],
>               PARAMETER["False northing",0,
>                   LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
>                   ID["EPSG",8807]]],
>           CS[Cartesian,2],

what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are providing `projectRaster` with a "wkt" representation of a coordinate reference system, but it expects a "proj4" representation. To fix this, you can do

```
img.merc <- projectRaster(x, crs = "+init=epsg:3857")
```

As in

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
x <- raster(f)
merc <- projectRaster(x, crs = "+init=epsg:3857")
```

Comment: Gave this a shot but the action of assigning a new CRS to the img gives the same error :Error in CRS(x) : PROJ4 argument-value pairs must begin with +: ... "

Comment: I have added an example so that you can see that it works.